# Assigning to 'readonly' return result not allowed, but property is declared "readwrite"

Tags: objective-c, properties, compiler-errors

I have a class with `readwrite` `int` properties:

```
@interface PlayScene : UIView

@property (readwrite, assign) int Figure1;
@property (readwrite, assign) int Figure2;
@property (readwrite, assign) int Figure3;
```

But when I try to change the value of the properties, an error occurs:

```
[self Figure1] = 1;
```

> assigning to 'readonly' return result of an Objective-C message not allowed

What is the problem?

Comment: Please include the code you're using to "try to change their value".

Comment: Like methods, all @property declarations should always start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: And uppercase initial letters for class names: `GameOverMenu`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

wrong syntax!

call

```
[self setFigure1:1];
```

or

```
self.Figure1 = 1;
```

(it's the same, thanks to @synthesize [i hope you did add a synthesize]!)

And: BTW: you might use lowercase-camelcase for your instance variable. It's kind of global-common. :)