# Assigning to 'readonly' return results... global NSString

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, readonly, read-write

So what I have is an NSString that I want to be able to access in another class. In my RootViewController.h I have:

```
@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController

+(NSMutableString*)MY_STR;

@property (nonatomic, readwrite, retain) NSString *MY_STR;

@end
```

In my RootViewController.m:

```
static NSString* MY_STR;

@synthesize MY_STR;

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    //The NSDictionary and NSArray items (listOfItems, etc.) are called at top so don't worry about them

    NSDictionary *dictionary = [listOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"MovieTitles"];
    MY_STR = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

}

+(NSString*)MY_STR{
    return MY_STR;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [MY_STR release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

And now in my NewViewController class I want to write to the NSString MY_STR so in my .m I have:

```
#import "RootViewController.h"

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSDictionary *dictionary = [listOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"MovieTitles"];
    [RootViewController MY_STR] = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

But on this line:

```
[RootViewController MY_STR] = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

I am receiving this error:
"Assigning to 'readonly' return result of an objective-c message not allowed"

Any help would be awesome thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assigning to 'readonly' return result not allowed, but property is declared "readwrite"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10303508/assigning-to-readonly-return-result-not-allowed-but-property-is-declared-rea)

Answer (score 0):

Property names need to start with a lower case character. By convention all uppercase names are "# defines". Try "myStr" instead.

So this line is your problem:

[RootViewController MY_STR] = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

The left hand side is just returning a value its not a lvalue. What you need to do is add

```
+(void) setMyStr:(NSString*)str
{
   myStr = str; // assumes ARC
}
```

then

```
[RootViewController setMyStr:[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

You may not have gotten to Key Value Coding or properties yet, but to facilitate ObjectiveC uses a naming convention to do these. All ivars should start with a lower case letter, the reason being that the setter uses the variable name with the first letter capitalized, and prefixed with "set". So using "myStr" as a variable name (good CamelCase example, again the Apple way), you have a setter of "setMyStr:". Now in your case, where you are only using these two methods in the class, you could really use any method name you wanted - but its good to get into practice. When you use properties, and let the compiler synthesize the getter and setter for you, it will look exactly as shown above.

Comment: Thanks David. Same thing though. It's pointing at the "=" for the error, but I think you and everyone else already understood that.

Comment: Alright so I added this to my RootViewController:
+(void) setMyStr:(NSString*)str
{
    myStr = str;
}
Then changed to this in my NewViewController:
[RootViewController setMyStr:[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

Now I'm getting this warning:
"Class method '+setMySTr:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')"

Comment: Check your spelling ( and mine too) - use CamelCase, its the Apple way - myStr - only second phrase (and others) get capitalized. I guarantee that method if properly spelled will work! So the getter is -(NSString *)myStr; and the setter is +(void)setMyStr:(NSString *)val;

Comment: Weird I checked everything to check if there was any spelling mistakes, and no there aren't. So I'm not sure what the problem is.